# New cookie preferences - just what is that black bar, and how do I set it?

Tags: support

They're not asking whether you prefer chocolate or oatmeal-raisin (... we arn't judging but chocolate all the way).

SU's one of the early release sites for the new cookie preferences. [Official post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent) and any bug reports and issues go there.

So - you can pick which cookies you want to allow SE to set. If you want to customise - the defaults that SE provides seem actually fairly reasonable. This should be accountwide for a domain, but I probably would at least initially check on a bunch of accounts how it works as it gets rolled out

[image]

and you can look up what these cookies are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy#C0003-list), and find out what they do by clicking on the question mark next to each. You may need *some* third party cookies for using an external log in and some folks may choose to turn off tracking cookies and others.

Comment: as an aside, treat this as a community wiki - if you feel we need to add to it, or edit it in some way, feel free.